# Set a list to a Dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with `DateTimeIndex` with one column as such:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='D')

np.random.seed(seed=1)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': days, 'Col1': data})
df = df.set_index('Date')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                            Col1
Date
2020-08-04 18:10:47.730173    38
2020-08-05 18:10:47.730173    13
2020-08-06 18:10:47.730173    73
2020-08-07 18:10:47.730173    10
2020-08-08 18:10:47.730173    76
2020-08-09 18:10:47.730173     6
2020-08-10 18:10:47.730173    80
2020-08-11 18:10:47.730173    65
```

I want to add a column called Col2 with NaN values and fill SOME values only with a List.
This is what I have attempted below:

```
# The code below doesn't work as intended
df['Col2'] = np.nan
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].astype(object)

# Fails with: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
df.iloc[4, df.columns.get_loc('Col2')] = [1.1, 2.2]
```

My intention is to get something like this:

```
                            Col1 Col2
Date
2020-08-04 18:10:47.730173    38  NaN
2020-08-05 18:10:47.730173    13  NaN
2020-08-06 18:10:47.730173    73  NaN
2020-08-07 18:10:47.730173    10  NaN
2020-08-08 18:10:47.730173    76  [1.1, 2.2]
2020-08-09 18:10:47.730173     6  NaN
2020-08-10 18:10:47.730173    80  NaN
2020-08-11 18:10:47.730173    65  NaN
```

How do I set a specific cell value to a List? I want pandas to store the list, it doesn't matter what format it is stored in, as long as I can retrieve it later.

The intention is readable code. Performance is not a factor as this operation will execute a handful of times.

Comment: My reaction is **not to**. Pandas and list-valued cells don't usually go along very well, not to mention modifying individual cells in a dataframe is not ideal either.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive here?

Comment: There will be few set operations, like a max of 10 assignments, my intention is not performance, but having a more readable code.

Comment: whats the criteria for adding in the values?

Comment: @Manakin there are 6 columns, this 7th column will have values in some cells if the other 6 columns matched some conditions. So, separating this into an independent NumPy would make having related data grouped in one row hard to track

Comment: try `np.select` you can specify all your conditions and hit them in one go see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627750/pandas-update-a-column-with-an-if-statement)